# SQL SELECT clause column adding row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot belive what I am witnessing. I have to reconsider all my knowing and 10 years experince in SQL after having to do with this simple query:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN SUM(COALESCE(lids_sids.counter, 0)) - SUM(COALESCE(lids_sids.leaved, 0)) > 0 
            THEN '1' 
            ELSE '2' 
        END as connected
FROM books
JOIN `lines` as l ON books.lid = l.id
LEFT JOIN lids_sids ON l.id = lids_sids.lid
```

I get **1 row** even if books.lid does not contain lines.id. The result is '2'

If I do:

```
SELECT books.id
FROM books
JOIN `lines` as l ON books.lid = l.id
LEFT JOIN lids_sids ON l.id = lids_sids.lid
```

I get **0 rows** as I was expecting also in the first query.

I was convinced that rows could be added and removed only by setting JOIN, WHERE, GROUP BY clauses. Now I learn that changing the content of SELECT clause can alter the rows number. Crazy ! I'm using mysql.

```
Table books.lid contains the values: 6, 207, 220, 285, 307, 326
while lines.id: 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74
lids_sids.lid: 68
```

books.lid never matches lines.id and table lids_sids should never been considered.

Comment: Can you add your data in results?

Comment: The first query returns one record and one field. 2 as result

Comment: It will be helpful if you edit your question giving sample data.

Comment: Its because you are using `coalesce` .

Comment: If you write `SELECT SUM(1) FROM empty_table` you'll get a result with a single row.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the aggregation function SUM. It will always return a single value / row.

if you would do something like:

```
SELECT SUM(books.id)
FROM books
JOIN `lines` as l ON books.lid = l.id
LEFT JOIN lids_sids ON l.id = lids_sids.lid
```

you'd also get a single value even though there aren't any records in the tables that get joined.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on.  First, an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` returns exactly one row.  Always.  Your query is an aggregation query because of the `SUM()` in the `SELECT`.

Your query (simplified a bit and using table aliases):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN SUM(COALESCE(ls.counter, 0)) > SUM(COALESCE(ls.leaved, 0)) 
             THEN '1' 
             ELSE '2' 
        END) as connected
FROM books b JOIN
     lines l
     ON b.lid = l.id LEFT JOIN
     lids_sids ls
     ON l.id = ls.lid;
```

The row is going to contain either 1 or 2.  Which will it contain?  Well, the `COALESCE()` doesn't do very much.  `SUM()` ignores `NULL` values (treats them as 0 anyway).  But, if no rows match, you'll still get a `NULL` value.  Hence, with no rows, "2" is returned because the condition is not true.

If you want `1` in this case, then move the COALESCE()`*outside* the`SUM()`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(ls.counter), 0) > COALESCE(SUM(ls.leaved), 0))
             THEN '1' 
             ELSE '2' 
        END) as connected
FROM books b JOIN
     lines l
     ON b.lid = l.id LEFT JOIN
     lids_sids ls
     ON l.id = ls.lid;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is there a way to avoid that unwanted row when there are actually no results using SUM in the SELECT clause?